# Group by indexed column performs table scan

Tags: postgresql

I have a table of orders, each with an associated account. I want to count the number of orders per account. The query is trivial

```
 select account, count(*) from orders group by account
```

The table has an index

```
create index idx_orders__account__symbol on orders (account, symbol)
```

So I'm expecting this to be fast, however this is what the query planner has in mind.

```
Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=463654.68..474273.83 rows=41915 width=17)
  Group Key: account
  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=463654.68..473435.53 rows=83830 width=17)
        Workers Planned: 2
        ->  Sort  (cost=462654.65..462759.44 rows=41915 width=17)
              Sort Key: account
              ->  Partial HashAggregate  (cost=459017.44..459436.59 rows=41915 width=17)
                    Group Key: account
                    ->  Parallel Seq Scan on orders  (cost=0.00..435881.96 rows=4627096 width=9)
```

I know that counting rows depends on what this transaction can see, hense the internal columns (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-system-columns.html), but I had always assumed that the index had something similar, and that this kind of group by query would be an index only operation - like it would be in MySQL.

Can somebody explain why the index is not used?

Note: we are using Amazon Aurora PostgreSQL Serverless 2

Edit: I found the section on index-only scans enlightening, especially

> In short, while an index-only scan is possible given the two
> fundamental requirements, it will be a win only if a significant
> fraction of the table's heap pages have their all-visible map bits
> set. But tables in which a large fraction of the rows are unchanging
> are common enough to make this type of scan very useful in practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The index has no visibility information.

There can be two explanations:

1. `VACUUM` has not been run on the table recently, so enough pages are not all-visible to make an index-only scan unattractive.
2. The table is narrow enough that a sequential scan is cheap enough. You could try to `SET enable_sort = off;` to see if PostgreSQL is right.

Comment: The table is 3.2GB the index is 228MB

Comment: Even if I use a left bounded search postgres refuses to use the index. If I say `where account = XYZ` I get an index only scan. but if I do `where account = 'XYZ%'` it scans. Even without the group by `explain select count(*) from orders where account like 'XYZ%'` show a scan on the orders table. It feels like it is refusing to use the index unless you specify the exact account. Normal index visdom says you can use a multi colum index as long as you are using the columns from left to right.

Comment: Also, if the index has no transaction visibility, then my understanding of "Index scan only" must be wrong. I though "Index only scan" meant that Postgres did not have to load the rows from disk, as the query can be satisfied from the index alone. However, if transaction visibility is attached to the row, then it must be loaded to determine if it is visible to the current transaction. Am I wrong ?

Comment: You are right in your last comment. That's why it is essential to `VACUUM` the table, so that the *visibility map* is updated.

Comment: In this particular table a row is inserted and then updated once (within 90 days on insert).  I can see that Amazon ran their auto-vacuum 20 days ago, so there are only 500K which are inserted/updated after that.  You speak of visibility map as it is it an independant thing from the record, but that is not my understanding of the internal columns.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/storage-vm.html

Comment: Thanks for the reference, I think I get it now :). If you are doing a group by {column} of the entire table, all pages would need to have the `all-visible` bit set for this to be an index-only scan, which is extremely unlikely. It still seems a bit strange that the query planner, doesn't consult the index on wildcards, since the index could tell it that only x  pages needed to be examined, rather than scanning a 3G table. Honestly this is one of the only cases where I feel Postgres is inferior to MySQL, in MySQL any left-bounded query always use the index (But MySQL have a lot of other issues)

Comment: There is no wildcard in your question. It is not necessary for *all* pages to be all-visible. Did you run `VACUUM` as I recommended? If you `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)` a query with an index-only scan, you get the number of "heap fetches", that is, the number of rows where the page was not all-visible.